# Drive writing problem

Tags: windows, linux, hard-drive, fat32

Ive a fat32 drive...when i save a file on it on linux . open it in windows the file is not visible...the space occupied by that file is also not accounted for...the vice versa is also true...any idea why??

Comment: This is a removable drive? Are you cleanly ejecting it on both OS's before opening it on the other? Stating which Linux distro and which Windows version would help to clarify the question a bit.

Comment: close as no-longer-relevant: not followed up after migration.  it's been a month, let it rest in piece.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is only the one filesystem on the drive? You're not mounting different filesystems in each OS...

Is this one specific file?